# Metro: Why is binding from XAML to a property defined in code-behind not working?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, code-behind, windows-runtime

I am attempting to adapt a Windows Metro-style app sample slightly by binding the title text to a property defined in code-behind, but I can't seem to get it to work. Reading the blog post titled [Bind from XAML to property defined in code-behind](http://blog.jayway.com/2011/05/17/bind-from-xaml-to-property-defined-in-code-behind/), I am trying out "Solution 1".

Here is my XAML source (simplified):

```
<UserControl x:Class="... .MainPage" x:Name="UserControlSelf"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="1366">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootGridStyle}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="TitlePanel">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button x:Name="BackButton" Click="BackButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="{Binding ElementName=UserControlSelf, Path=Title}" Style="{StaticResource TitleStyle}" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here is my code-behind (simplified):

```
public partial class MainPage
{
    private string _title;

    public MainPage()
    {
        _title = "Test";
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return _title;
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

I set a breakpoint on the line `return _title;` in the getter of the `Title` property. When I debug the app, I see the back button, but the title text block control is blank (no text) and the breakpoint is not triggered:

[image: Screenshot of the modified Metro-style app running, showing the back button, but no title]

I set a breakpoint in the autogenerated C# code for the XAML file and verified that `UserControlSelf` is identical to `this` within `InitializeComponent()`.

How do I bind the `Text` of the title text block control to the `Title` property defined in code-behind?

Comment: May I ask you why you would like to bind a property defined in code behind (and not a property of a view-model, i.e why did you choose to not use MVVM pattern)?

Comment: @ken2k: In this case I felt that MVVM would not be appropriate because there is only one model object; there is only one title.

Comment: Examine the app's debug output for binding errors. Also try using `RelativeSource` instead of `ElementName`.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy: Where is the debug output?

Comment: Also, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11706439/1493272).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to get it working. Instead of messing around with `ElementName` and `Path`, I simply set the `MainPage` instance's `DataContext` to an object *other than the `MainPage` instance* that had a `Title` property. I then changed the `Text` attribute of the title text block to `{Binding Title}`.

It does not appear to be necessary for the data context object to implement [`Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.aspx); however, by doing so, the binding automatically behaves like a "one way" binding.

I originally tried setting `this.DataContext = this;`, but, as I found out, **that does not work**. If I set it to a POCO or view model instance, then the binding is established.

It would be interesting to know why `this.DataContext = this;` is erroneous, but at least I can now proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Can't test Metro app right now, but maybe you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so the binding can work.

In your code behind:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}

public string Title
{
    get
    {
        return this._title;
    }

    set
    {
        if (this._title != value)
        {
            this._title = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }
}
```

Also change

```
 _title = "Test";
```

to

```
 this.Title = "Test";
```

Comment: Sorry that it is taking me a while to respond. I managed to brick my Developer Preview installation when I encountered a CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT issue. I am reinstalling and will report back...

Comment: I tried implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but this does not fix the problem. I also tried calling `InitializeComponent()` before setting `this.Title = "Test"`, calling `InitializeComponent()` after, and calling `NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");` explicitly within the load event handler of `MainPage`. Nothing seems to work. Note that I am using [`INotifyPropertyChanged` from the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Data`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used Metro, but in WPF, that won't work because `Title` needs to be a Dependency Property. Change your code behind like this:

```
public partial class MainPage
{


    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    static MainPage()
    {
        TitleProperty= DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Title",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MainPage));
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = "Test";
    }
}
```

This caught me out yesterday, it's so easy to forget to do.

Answer (score 0):

This technique always works for me

```
Text="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=Parent.Title}"
```

This assumes that the user control’s child element name is “LayoutRoot” which it is by default.

Comment: I just tried this, but it didn't work. It seems to be impossible to bind to properties of the user control. Maybe this a problem with the Developer Preview that will be corrected with the release of Windows 8?

Comment: Hmm it should work. Register the property as a dependency property.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Register the property as a dependency property". (I'm very new to WPF/Silverlight/XAML.)