# How to update a data bound combobox when the source data changes?

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm working on a C# Metro style app for Windows 8, and I'm having a problem getting my data bound combo box to update when the source data changes.

Here's the data source:

```
public class Range
{
    public string range_name { get; set; }
    public string range_description { get; set; }
    public int min { get; set; }
    public int max { get; set; }
}

static List<Range> ranges = new List<Range>
{
    new Range { range_name = "Foo", range_description = "Foo: (0-10)", min = 0, max = 10},
    new Range { range_name = "Bar", range_description = "Bar: (5-15)", min = 5, max = 15},
    new Range { range_name = "Baz", range_description = "Baz: (10-20)", min = 10, max = 20},
    new Range { range_name = "Custom", range_description = "Custom: (0-20)", min = 0, max = 20}
};
```

And the combo box:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ComboBox Name="combo_range" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Range}" DisplayMemberPath="range_description" SelectedValuePath="range_name" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Range}" SelectionChanged="combo_range_SelectionChanged"/>
</Grid>
```

The user can manipulate the min/max range range of the 'custom' range in the app, but the combo box only updates when I change away from that record and then change back to 'custom'.

What do I need to do to force the combo box to update in real time when the source data changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try implementing [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in your Range class:

```
public class Range : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Declare the event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _range_name;
    private string _range_description;
    private int _min;
    private int _max;

    public string range_name
    {
        get { return this._range_name; }
        set
        {
            _range_name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("range_name");  
        }  // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
    }
    public string range_description
    {
        get { return this._range_description; }
        set
        {
            _range_description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("range_description");
        }
    }
    public int min
    {
        get { return this._min; }
        set
        {
            _min=value;
            OnPropertyChanged("min");
        }
    }
    public int max
    {
        get { return this._max; }
        set
        {
            _max = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("max");
        }
    }

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestions. I tried both of these approaches, but I don't think they will work in a Metro style app.

BindingExpression and GetDefaultView are valid in System.Windows.Data, but not in the Metro equivalent Windows.UI.Xaml.Data

Comment: Thanks - this does exactly what I need, and works with my Metro style app.

Comment: Glad to hear that your problem is solved. I would suggest you to read about [*OneWay and TwoWay binding modes*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode.aspx) :-)

Comment: I'd just like to add that instead of manually implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, consider inheriting from BindableBase (included in the Common folder in the Grid App and Split App template projects). BindableBase makes it much simpler to add properties with notification and gets around the need to pass quoted strings to OnPropertyChanged (quoted strings don't refactor properly).